# QAbstractListModel returning unexpcted result on Qt::DisplayRole

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have created a very minimal QAbstractListModel with two roles, `display` and `test`

```
InvoiceTabModel::InvoiceTabModel(QObject *parent): QAbstractListModel(parent)
{

}

QVariant InvoiceTabModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(index)
    if(role == 123)
        return QVariant("testRole");
    return QVariant("displayRole");
}

int InvoiceTabModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent)
    return 3;
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> InvoiceTabModel::roleNames() const
{
    return { {Qt::DisplayRole, "display"}, {123, "test"} };
}
```

I attached this model to a repeater

```
Repeater{
    id: invoiceTab
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: invoice.tabmodel
    Button{
        width: 100
        height: parent.height
        text: test
        //text: display
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I use `display` role the text is displayed as `2`, but when I use `test` in qml, the string is displaying correctly

Using `test` Role

[image]

When using the `display` role

[image]

Where does this `2` come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`display` is a property of Button.

When using data coming from a model, always use the `model.` prefix to disambiguate (`model.display`).